# How To Output The Total Number of Rows Which Have been Inserted AND Update?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am attempting to submit multiple rows of data row-by-row, and when completed, I want to submit a summary to push a notification out to everyone, however what I am looking for is a little more advanced, and all my searches have not been providing anything which I've found to be useful.

**What I Would Like To Achieve:**

1. Attempt to insert

   - **TRY:** Check if they're already in a group

     - **TRUE:** `UPDATE` their `group_id`
     - **FALSE:** `INSERT` as planned

       - Will also need to update another table
   - **CATCH:** *- Based on the above*

     - **Count Update** eg; 2
     - **Count insert** eg; 13
   - **OUTPUT:** *- What the final notification output should look like*

     - **Example 1:** 15 members have been added to your group
     - **Example 2:** A total of 15 members have been added to your group; 13 members added, 2 members have been transferred from another group.

Once I know how to catch the values to create the output, then I know how to submit the notification to be pushed through to everyone.

**Current Insert**

```php
$Store_Group_Members= new Database();
$Store_Group_Members->query("
    INSERT INTO group_members (group_id, user_id, user_position)
    VALUES (:group_id, :user_id, :user_position)"
);
foreach($data as $user_id => $user_info) {

    $Store_Group_Members->bind(":group_id", $_SESSION['group_id']);
    $Store_Group_Members->bind(":user_id", $user_id);
    $Store_Group_Members->bind(":user_position", $user_info["position"]);

    try {
        $Store_Group_Members->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) { }

}
```

**How can I process the insert/update whilst outputting the total rows which have been inserted / updated?**

Comment: **In the foreach loop:**  use a `select` statement to determine whether an existing record exists, then if exists (1) execute an `update` (else (2) execute an `insert`). **After that** - use the total number of (1) and (2) to construct your notification message and then send the result to everyone